# letters and spacing in Arabic -- bug in OpenType layout of LuaLaTeX

Tags: fonts, luatex, arabic, opentype, luaotfload

I perceive the following unwanted outcome:
[image: issue with opentype engine]

Two issues:

1. In the first line, the last word on the right has a small gap between the second and the third letter from the right that is not supposed to be there.
2. In the second line, the word is entirely jumbled up.

I had issue #1 before in June 2013. I wrote to Khaled Hosny about it and he told me that it is a

> bug in the OpenType layout engine currently used by LuaLaTeX.

The solution back in 2013 was to update `luaotfload` through issuing `luaotfload-tool --update`.

Today, that does not do the trick.

So what am I going to do? I am very surprised to suddenly see the old error again after 2,5 years. What happened?

The MWE, in case somebody is interested:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[  Script=Arabic,%
                            Numbers=Arabic,%
                            Scale=MatchLowercase%
                                ]{Amiri}%
    \newfontfamily\arabicfontz[ Script=Arabic,%
                            Numbers=Arabic,%
                            Scale=1.6%
                                ]{Arabic Typesetting}%
\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]       % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\arabtextz}[1]      % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfontz #1\egroup}
\begin{document}
\noindent Font: Amiri => wrong: \arabtext{تعريف}\\
Font: Arabic Typesetting => very wrong: \arabtextz{تعريف}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this happen with all fonts or just these two? Would you be interested in solutions with other fonts?

Comment: Well, I recognised it with `Amiri`, which I decided to use. I checked with `Arabic Typesetting` just to see and was surprised by the even worse result. I checked with `Arial` and it was fine. So I am guessing that it depends to a degree on the font, but still something has recently gone bad. I did not recognise the error a few days ago. -- Anyway, I decided to use Amiri, but of course, tell me about other fonts! What do you use?

Comment: I don't speak Arabic (yet), so none, but since you say Arial was fine, the fonts might have something to do with it?

Comment: Scheherazade and Lateef produce good results.

Comment: Do you get the same problems with XeLaTeX as LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Other fonts that fail: Reem Kufi and Aref Ruqaa, from Khaled Hosny.  I didn’t notice a problem with these fonts when I last tried them a couple of weeks ago; perhaps there’s some unfortunate interaction between the way the fonts are made and the new version of `luaotfload`?

Comment: Noto Naskh Arabic and Noto Kufi Arabic look OK to me. (Although I don't know enough about Arabic to be certain.) Or have I just not updated to enjoy the latest bugs?

Comment: you might be interested in [LuaTeX Harfbuzz shaper](https://github.com/michal-h21/luatex-harfbuzz-shaper)

Comment: @michal.h21 : interesting! what exactly is this?

Comment: It is alternative font loader for LuaTeX. It uses Harfbuzz library (it is the same as XeTeX uses) for text shaping, Binary library must be installed first, so it is little bit harder to install. It is definitely not bug free, so some testers are welcomed :)

Comment: @cfr : I don't have a clue about XeLaTeX…

Comment: @ClintEastwood Just compile with XeLaTeX rather than LuaLaTeX and see if it works. Unless you are using Lua script stuff, chances are good your document will compile without changes. However, I really meant just to test your MWE with your fonts and see if they worked correctly with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @cfr : In `XeLaTeX` it works fine. No error.

Comment: I have to say that I really hope that this gets solved soon -- if not, I am in real big trouble.

Comment: Is XeLaTeX or the alternative font loader an option? Has the bug been reported? If you want it fixed, tell somebody about it....

Comment: I have an issue about vowels not being aligned above the right letters in Arabic ([287150](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287150)) that may be related to this one: see EDIT2 in my initial question.

Comment: I don’t have Arabic Typesetting, but the problem no longer appears in Amiri with `luaotfload` version 2.6-fix-5 2016-01-22.