# Arabic in LuaLaTeX: Why do I get the vowels typeset RTL in LTR mode?

Tags: luatex, arabic

This mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newfontfamily\libertine{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]       % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\textdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}

\begin{document}

As you can see, this is rightly typeset LTR, but the vowels,
which are seemingly RTL: \arabtext{دَخَلَ مُبتَسِمًا}.

\end{document}
```

gives me this:
[image]

I suspect this is a regression, but I may be wrong. Any advice would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** To be more precise, each vowel seems to be moved one letter back (i.e. to the right).

**EDIT2:** With `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial Unicode MS}` vowels are back to normal. I think that this issue may be related to
[285674](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285674)

Comment: Are you forced to use `lualatex`? I feel like it's easier to work with non-Latin scripts and fonts in `xelatex`.

Comment: @Alenanno You're right. Of course I'm not, but it happens that I'm currently using `lua` to translate latin-based ArabTeX input to have Arabic in `xml` code, with almost the same features `arabxetex` provides. Hence the idea to make such a package for `lualatex`.

Comment: Well, with `\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Arial Unicode MS}` vowels are back to normal. This issue seems related to [285674](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285674). I edit my post.

Comment: Using the same font but `xelatex` I actually [got a different result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/deTPF.png). Is this correct?

Comment: Vowels are at the right places in your example, but Arabic is typeset LTR. Try loading `arabxetex` like this: `\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}`, then put in your document: `... seemingly LTR: \textarabic{daxala mubtasimaN}.` Don't forget to comment out any polyglossia related Arabic settings.

Comment: This is indeed related to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285674. There is an interim solution for the meantime reported here: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/318 . Upon comparison of an erroneous pdf with a correct pdf, I could see that there are quite a number of errors (including the one reported here) that have recently been introduced through an update in November.

Comment: Thank you so much @clinteastwood the workaround suggested by phi-gamma solves this issue. I was struggling with the installation of luaharfbuzz which requires lua ~> 5.2 (I have 5.3). Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I hope nonetheless that the issue will be genuinely solved soon.

Comment: @RobertAlessi : Would you mind registering at github and mention your case in [my issue report](http://www.github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/318) there as well? It should be known there that I am not the only one with these issues. More and more people use LuaLaTeX for Arabic and other RTL languages -- they *all* may have the same problem.

Comment: @clinteastwood: Sure, I will do that later on today when I'm back home.